# Database change notifications in asp.net core using signalr and sqldependency

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, sqldependency, asp.net-core-signalr

If I made any changes in SQL table row then UI should automatically refresh the new changes without F5 or reloading the browser.

I have already tried this in asp.net mvc and its working good but I'm unable to do in asp.net mvc core..

Comment: It’s quite unclear what the question is. What UI? What database? How are they connected here? If it works already on one, what’s different with Core? Please explain more

Comment: When the MS-SQL database table changes on the back-end, I want to see the change reflected right-away on the client web page without having to refresh/reload the page. And i need to do that using dotnetcore using SignalR with SQLDependency.

Comment: So what’s not working under Core?

Comment: this code is work  for asp. net core mvc 3.0 with Postgresql  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468162/how-can-i-listen-postgresql-database-with-signalr-core-in-net-core-project/59478650#59478650

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a sql backplane solution which as of now and this [github isssue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5277), is not supported under core.

Read that issue for more details. But they are recommending the use of a Redis backplane which is support as in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 0):

You can detect changes using the SqlDependency class and then broadcast them to registered clients using SignalR. I wrote a sample using pre-Core SignalR, which is available at https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/broadcasting-database-changes-through-signalr. In order to make it work with ASP.NET Core SignalR you need to retrieve the hub using the service locator (HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService>). Also, there is a change that you must do to the client-side code.